# Font awesome does not support in idxbroker header in firefox browser

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I used font awesome icon in my header in WordPress theme (like ph icon) but when my site redirect to idxbroker site, font icon not support in Firefox browser. i have real estate site and purchase idx platinum account.

I used dynamic header integration in idx pages.

I used below code in my .htaccess file but not work.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a CDN to get font awesome in with out modifying your .htaccess

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/